# testing last line of log files using ANT

Tags: ant, automation, batch-file

I have couple of bat files which run further files to build the project. its a hectic process. I am writign a master ant build file to do all ..

There is an BAT files, which print BUILD SUCCESSFUL on console when it runs successfully. The BUILD SUCCESSFUL is the last line of the console out put.

I have written this in my ant script so far

```
<project name="MyProject" basedir=".">
    <property name="buildC" value="${basedir}/build-C" />
    <exec dir="${buildC}" executable="cmd" os="Windows XP">
        <arg line="/c test.bat > test.log"/>
    </exec>

    <loadfile property="buildC.log" srcFile="${buildC}/test.log">
    </loadfile>

</project>
```

I wana test if **the last line of *test.log*** file is *BUILD SUCCESSFUL* or not. if it is then execute next task, otherwise FAIL.

I have tried to use *fail* task but din help. could someone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can examine the `buildC.log` property using a nested condition of a `fail` task:

```
<fail message="test.bat failed">
   <condition>
       <not>
           <matches pattern="${line.separator}BUILD SUCCESSFUL$" string="${buildC.log}" />
       </not>
   </condition>
</fail>
```

You may need to tweak the pattern a little to get it working, depends on exactly what is written by the test.bat script.
The `matches` by default applies to the whole string, so the above will only match if the success message constitutes the last line of the file.

You might also consider capturing the output from test.bat using the `exec` task `outputproperty` attribute.

```
<exec dir="." executable="sh" outputproperty="buildC.log">
    <arg line="/c test.bat" />
</exec>
```

(Note the shell redirect has been removed in the `arg` line.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last line, use a filterchain with tailfilter lines="1", see [Ant Manual FilterChains](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html)
afterwards use some Ant Addon with if/else construct like [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) or [Antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) to check the property =

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <loadfile srcfile="your.log" property="buildsuccess">
  <filterchain>
   <tailfilter lines="1" />
    <!-- also possible if needed -->
    <trim/>
    <striplinebreaks/>
    <!-- also possible if needed // -->
  </filterchain>
 </loadfile>

 <fl:choose>
  <fl:when test="'${buildsuccess}' eq 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL'">
   <echo>execute new task..</echo>
  </fl:when>
  <fl:otherwise>
   <fail message="Houston we have a problem.."/>
  </fl:otherwise>
</fl:choose>
</project>
```

or use the standard ant way with condition =

```
<project default="main">

 <target name="checklog">
  <loadfile srcfile="props.txt" property="buildsuccess">
   <filterchain>
    <tailfilter lines="1" />
    <!-- // also possible if needed -->
    <trim/>
    <striplinebreaks/>
    <!-- also possible if needed // -->
   </filterchain>
  </loadfile>

  <condition property="buildOK">
   <equals arg1="${buildsuccess}" arg2="BUILD SUCCESSFUL"/>
  </condition>    
 </target>

 <target name="whatever">
  <fail message="Houston we have a problem.." unless="buildOK"/>   
  <!-- if not failed then you'll go on with your other tasks here .. -->    
 </target>

 <target name="main" depends="checklog,whatever"/>
</project>
```